# Перетаскивание элементов из окна в окно как в Админ-панели Django

Tags: django, django-admin, drag-n-drop

Необходимо реализовать возможность перетаскивания/перекидывания различного набора элементов из одного текстового поля в другое путём перетаскивания элементов либо их выбора и перемещения с помощью кнопки, как в панели администрирования Django при назначении прав пользователям.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально задача ставится реализовать возможность выбора нескольких специализаций для сотрудника, проходящего регистрацию в системе.

Порекомендуйте, плиз, что для такого решения возможно использовать - вариант, реализованный в администраторской Django-панели, если эти средства встроены в Django, как применимый инструментарий, либо с помощью других инструментов?

Comment: Дело в том, что весь интерактив на страницах - это javascript. Собственно точно так же, как и Django использует во встроенной админке. Копать нужно именно в эту сторону

Comment: Безусловно, javascript. Знать бы ещё, как им воспользоваться из Django или, может, на аналогичные паттерны кто укажет?

Comment: Точно так-же, как используют js на любых других сайтах: подключение через тег `<script>`, размещение исходников в статике, jquery ил любая другая либа в помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drap & Drop

[Инструкция](https://professorweb.ru/my/javascript/jquery/level4/4_12.php)

[Библиотека](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Пишите скрипт на jQuery, который к нужным полям (по имени, или доп. атрибутам) будет применять `jquery-ui draggable`. Подключаете этот скрипт в `Media` формы или представления. Лучше в форму.

Что касается админки `django`, то логиук ее работы проще подглядеть в исходниках, а если кратко, то там тупо *"при нажатии на кнопки выделить все активные элементы из левого поля в правом. в левом поле поставть значение null"* . И `select` должен быть `multiple`